# Redux typescript exporting state of reducer in array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

So I'm having a problem wherein my reducer is undefined and I don't freaking understand what it means. It's working when it is not array but when array it is not working.

My code should be like this.
In my `groupSlice.ts` it is something like this

```
export interface GroupState {
    grouplist: (string)[];
}

const groupInitialState: GroupState = {
    grouplist:['Binary','Jhonny Sins']
}
export const createGroup = createSlice({
    name: 'group',
    initialState:groupInitialState,
    reducers:{  
        addGroup: (state,action) => {
            state.grouplist.push(action.payload)
        },
        subGroup: ( state,action ) => {
            state.grouplist.filter((group) => group != action.payload)
        }
    }
})
...
```

And then I store it here at my `store.ts`

```
import { configureStore, ThunkAction, Action } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { createGroup }  from '../features/counter/groupSlice';

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    groupings: createGroup.reducer,
  },
});

export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch;
export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>;
export type AppThunk<ReturnType = void> = ThunkAction<
  ReturnType,
  RootState,
  unknown,
  Action<string>
>;
```

And then the `hook.ts` to pass on my `state` in reducer.

```
import { TypedUseSelectorHook, useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import type { RootState, AppDispatch } from './store';

export const useAppDispatch = () => useDispatch<AppDispatch>();
export const useAppSelector: TypedUseSelectorHook<RootState> = useSelector;
```

but when I pass it here in my `Group.tsx` it says my `grouplist` is undefined even I already input a `an array at string[]`

```
import React,{ useState,useEffect } from 'react'

import styles from './Group.module.css'

import {
    addGroup,
    subGroup
} from './groupSlice';
import { useAppSelector, useAppDispatch } from '../../app/hooks';
import { RootState } from '../../app/store';

// HERE IS MY ERROR THAT DOESN"T WORK>
export const selectCount = (state: RootState) =>  {
    console.log(state.groupings?.grouplist)
    const groupList = state.groupings?.grouplist
    return groupList;
}

const Grouping = () => {

    const groups = useAppSelector(selectCount);
    const dispatch = useAppDispatch();
    const [groupName, setGroupName] = useState('');
      
    return (
        ...
    )
}

export default Grouping
```

So I'm trying to say that my `grouplist` is undefined but I don't know why since I already input a list values there. Can anyone spotted the mistake here? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In the `subGroup` reducer:

```
state.grouplist.filter(...)
```

This only returns the filtered array, it doesn't change it in place (unlike `push`), so you need to reassign it:

```
state.grouplist = state.grouplist.filter(...)
```

Comment: I'm sorry about that but that is not the solution I'm looking for haha, but yeah you are right about that. but that is not my problem hehe.

Comment: Did you try the Redux Devtools to check if your state is correctly initialized?

Comment: Yes, it says `undefined grouplist`.

Comment: Are you using Redux's provider?

Comment: Nope. Jist normal redux toolkit and react-redux.

Comment: I feel like it has some issue with `RootState` or I don't know..I'm just new with typescript redux. The syntax is quite frustrating.

Comment: Well then there is no way your component can access the state. You need to render the `Provider` component from Redux at the root of your app, passing the store as an argument.

Comment: Oh you mean the provider before the store...Yes I have it..Sorry I thought you were talking other things.

Comment: I badly need help lol..it really doesn't work when it is array I don't understand lol.

Comment: Could you make a minimal example in a codesandbox? Would be much easier to figure out what the problem is.

Comment: here is the codesandbox @Guillaume Brunerie..its working here https://codesandbox.io/s/rough-sky-uvyix7?file=/src/features/Grouping.tsx

but its not working in my browser.. I don't understand lol I'm so confused rn.